# Ionic2 building Android fails

Tags: android, cordova, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a project that has been under development for a few weeks and have been running fine in the browser with `ionic serve`.

I then proceeded to add the android platform however when I try to build it fails with a pretty generic message.

I tried the same with an out of the box build (created new project `ionic example start --v2`) then `ionic platform add android` and it builds and displays on the device just fine.

The outputs are different: Out of box...

```
ionic-app-scripts build
[17:02:31]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.47
[17:02:31]  build dev started ...
[17:02:31]  clean started ...
[17:02:31]  clean finished in 7 ms
[17:02:31]  copy started ...
[17:02:31]  transpile started ...
[17:02:34]  transpile finished in 2.66 s
[17:02:34]  webpack started ...
[17:02:34]  copy finished in 2.83 s
[17:02:41]  webpack finished in 6.89 s
[17:02:41]  sass started ...
[17:02:42]  sass finished in 1.19 s
[17:02:42]  build dev finished in 10.77 s
```

But this is mine that fails...

```
[17:09:04]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.42
[17:09:04]  build prod started ...
[17:09:04]  clean started ...
[17:09:04]  clean finished in 7 ms
[17:09:04]  copy started ...
[17:09:04]  ngc started ...
[17:09:05]  copy finished in 227 ms
[17:09:11]  can't resolve module apollo-client from C:/.../.tmp/app/app.module.ts
[17:09:11]  Error: can't find symbol undefined exported from module C:/.../node_modules/apollo-client/index.d.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/.../.tmp/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/.../.tmp/app/app.module.ts
[17:09:11]  ngc failed
[17:09:11]  ionic-app-script task: "build"
[17:09:11]  Error: Error
```

So the first difference is that my project calls `ngc` (angular compiler) and it seems to have an issue with the first module listed in app.module.ts, which in this case is the apollo-client.

I am not too knowledgeable in angular and the build process but it is strange to be that the out-of-box build does not call `ngc`.

Either way what could be done to get this to build and run on an android device?

***EDIT:***

Another difference found is that the out-of-box project does not generate a .tmp folder, which I presume is created by `ngc` itself.

I also added apollo into the out-of-box project and it still worked (without calling ngc.

Comment: Have not solved this. I started a clean project and moved the code over making sure it always run on the device. Now I am at the same point of development and it works without running ngc. Which is workable for now, but would eventually need ngc to work to produce release builds (and hopefully increase performance)